# How create a general legend which always remain on top of the plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I am writing a small report, wherein I have several plots, some plots are on a linear-linear scale, some are in log-linear scale, some in log-log. The problem I am facing is every time I change my scale it is becoming very difficult for me to adjust the legend. right now I am customized my legend using line command and circle command of graphics. Is there any way to fix this suppose my plot image size is 1500 (which is fixed for all of my plots), with respect to this can I set my legends.[image: example]. I don't have a

```
style1 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}]}
style2 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{8, 20}]}
style3 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{4, 18, 40}]}
p1 = Plot[Sin[π*x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate@style1];
p2 = Plot[Sin[2 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate@style2];
p3 = Plot[Sin[3 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate@style3];


s1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.004], AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}], 
    Line[{{0, 14}, {1.5, 14}}], 
    Text[StyleForm["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(β\), \(1\)]\),", 
      FontSize -> 30], {2.5, 14}]}];
s2 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.004], AbsoluteDashing[{8, 20}], 
    Line[{{3.5, 14}, {5, 14}}], 
    Text[StyleForm["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(β\), \(2\)]\),", 
      FontSize -> 30], {6, 14}]}];
s3 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.004], AbsoluteDashing[{4, 18, 40}], 
    Line[{{7, 14}, {10, 14}}], 
    Text[StyleForm["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(β\), \(3\)]\),", 
      FontSize -> 30], {10.5, 14}]}];

Show[p1, p2, p3,s1,s2,s3, PlotRange -> All]
```

The above plot is on a linear-linear scale I looking trying to fix the general legend for all type of scale.

Comment: Please add the code you're using to generate the legend. Otherwise, it is impossible for anyone to tell what's the problem with your legend

Comment: Can we use the above code as a reference code, because  it is pretty big.

Comment: I'm not asking for the full code with actual data (in fact, the example you have is much better) - but since your example image has a legend, and you are asking about how to position legends, it would help a lot if you could add the code you're currently using to create and position the legend. Even better would be if you could add the legend to the example above, and add a second example with e.g. log-log scaling and a legend that shows how the legend is no longer working in that case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a legend using your `style1`, `style2`, `style3`:

```
legend = LineLegend[Directive[#2] & @@@ {style1, style2, style3}, 
      Subscript[β, #] & /@ Range[3], LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendMarkerSize -> 60];
```

and use it as `Epilog` in `Show` controlling the position with the second argument of `Inset`:

```
Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.07],
  Epilog -> Inset[legend, {.5, 1.1}]]
```

[image]

or place it `Above` the plot using [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html):

```
Legended[Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All], Placed[legend, Above]]
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work for Log-Linear scale, because last time I am trying to put , It was not adjusted properly.

Comment: @acoustics, both should work. Try, for example,`Legended[LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}], Placed[legend, {.5, 1}]]`. For the first approach, you can use `LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[legend, Scaled@{.5, 1}]]`.

Comment: I have tried modifying the code little bit by introducing a new legend circle,  but I am not getting exactly what I wanted to do. Instead I am getting a straight line

Comment: `style1 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}]}
style2 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{8, 20}]}
style3 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 25]};legend = LineLegend[
  Directive[#2] & @@@ {style1, style2, style3}, {Text[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(S\)]\),", 30]], 
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(AS\)]\)", 30]], 
   Text[Style["FEM", 30]]}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 60]`

Comment: @acoustics, does `style3 = PlotStyle -> {Black}; legend = 
 LineLegend[
  Directive[#2] & @@@ {style1, style2, style3}, {Style[
    Subscript[\[Beta], S], 30], Style[Subscript[\[Beta], AS], 30], 
   Text[Style["FEM", 30]]}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 60, 
  LegendMarkers -> {None, None, {"\[EmptyCircle]", 25}} ]` give what you need?

Comment: No, I am trying to have just circled in my last legend, but the one you suggested gives line passing through the circle.

Comment: @acoustics, change `style3=...` to `style3 = PlotStyle -> {"LineColor" -> None};`